# TypeError: '<=' not supported between instances of 'int' and 's

Tags: python, function, pagination, gitlab-api

I'm using a function to grab some users from Gitlab API but I wish to paginate from the headers and store all users not just one page of 100 users, for some reason I need to add int somewhere in my code but I'm uncertain where, please can anyone assist:

```
    # Base URI of Gitlab API from our private Gitlab Instance
baseuri = "https://git.tools.dev.mycompany.net/api/v4"

# Function to grab users and put objects in S3 bucket:
def get_gitlab_users(access_token=access_token, baseuri=baseuri):
    next_page = 1
    result = []
    headers = {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "Authorization": "Bearer {}".format(access_token),
    }

    # Paginate by using x-total-pages from the headers received in the response
    # https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/#pagination-link-header
    url = f"{baseuri}/users/?per_page=100&active=true&without_project_bots=true&page={next_page}"
    req = http.request(method="GET", url=url, headers=headers)
    result.extend(json.loads(req.data))

    while next_page <= req.headers["x-total-pages"]:
        url = f"{baseuri}/users/?per_page=100&active=true&without_project_bots=true&page={next_page}"
        req = http.request(method="GET", url=url, headers=headers)
        result.extend(json.loads(req.data))
```

This is where the error occurs:

```
while next_page <= req.headers["x-total-pages"]:
TypeError: '<=' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'str'
```

Comment: "This is where the error occurs:" Okay, so did you try to read and understand the error message? Which line of code do you think has the error? What do you think is going wrong, according to what the error says? What do you suppose is the type of `next_page`, and of `req.headers["x-total-pages"]`? (Do you understand what *type* means in programming?)

Comment: "for some reason I need to add int somewhere in my code but I'm uncertain where" Well, I guess it should be in the place where the error occurs, right? What makes more sense: should we try to compare a number to a number, or a string to a string? (I assume you understand why comparing a number to a string will not work.) Which side of the comparison seems to have the number, and which side the string? Therefore, which side needs to be converted? If you think through the problem like this, what is actually confusing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume `req.headers["x-total-pages"]` is a string, so cast it to `int` explicitly like this:
`int(req.headers["x-total-pages"])`
and you should be fine (since you'll be comparing two `int`s and not an `int` to a `str`

Comment: Thank you so much, I'm very new to a lot of this and learning every day so a kind and simple answer is what I needed. Thank you.